# how make drop down not change after refresh in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have drop down in HTML :

```
<div>
    <select onchange="sesi(this.value)">
        <option id="tgl" value="tahun">PerBulan</option>
        <option id="bln" value="tgl">PerTanggal</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group" id="dateThn" >
        <input type="text" id="datepicker-autoclose" class="form-control" value="{{ Helpers.showTgl(tanggal, 'Y-m') }}" />           
    </div>
    <div  id="dateTgl" style="display: none;" >
        <input type="text" id="datepickerTgl" value="{{ Helpers.showTgl(tanggal, 'Y-m-d') }}" />         
    </div>
</div>
```

with javascript :

```
<script>
    function sesi(sesi){
        if (sesi == 'tgl') {
            $('#dateTgl').show();
            $('#dateThn').hide();
        } else {
            $('#dateTgl').hide();
            $('#dateThn').show();
        }}
</script>
```

Why when I chose Pertanggal and refresh page drop down back to default .
and default is perbulan.

how I solved ?

Comment: do you want the other option `PerTanggal` to be the default one?

Comment: You need a back-end to save what the user chose

Comment: When you refresh the page, the entire page gets reloaded. When it is reloaded, ur selection will surely be gone. If you want to save your selection as Kartik mentioned you need to have a back-end so you can save the users selection. If that is not what you are looking for maybe rephrase the question

Comment: `{{ Helpers.showTgl(tanggal, 'Y-m') }}` is this backend code?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no, I want when click PerTanggal and refresh, interface dropdrown is PerTanggal, not back to default.

Comment: @KartikPrasad I dont know, how to add back end.

Comment: @Uraforclain yes, is that I mean. but I dont know how to add in back end. maybe you can teach me

Comment: @SudarpoChong yes, is that just helper to appear date.

Comment: @jazuli_18, your profile says you are a back-end developer so I assumed. You need to learn more about web development find an easy full stack tutorial to get you started. Other than that I would say you could save the data to the users local storage and get the selection from there

Comment: yes thanks for recomendation @KartikPrasad

Answer (score 0):

> Why when I chose Pertanggal and refresh page drop down back to default . and default is perbulan.

If I guess correctly, you're having issue with postback. When you select `pertanggal` option, your page is refreshed and dropdown is back to `PerBulan`

Handle a change event with jquery as documented here https://api.jquery.com/change/.

And add `event.preventDefault()` to prevent postback.

```js
$("#myselect").change(function(e) {
  var selectedSesi = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedSesi);
  sesi(selectedSesi);
  
  e.preventDefault();
});

function sesi(sesi) {
  if (sesi == 'tgl') {
    $('#dateTgl').show();
    $('#dateThn').hide();
  } else {
    $('#dateTgl').hide();
    $('#dateThn').show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div>
  <select id="myselect" class="form-control" >
    <option id="" value="">--Select Something--</option>
    <option id="tgl" value="tahun">PerBulan</option>
    <option id="bln" value="tgl">PerTanggal</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="input-group" id="dateThn">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker-autoclose" 
      class="form-control" 
      value="{{ Helpers.showTgl(tanggal, 'Y-m') }}" />
  </div>
  <div id="dateTgl" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="datepickerTgl" 
      value="{{ Helpers.showTgl(tanggal, 'Y-m-d') }}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried and it works for me. What is it that you want actually?